# error with special characters when load .htm into a div with jquery

Tags: jquery, load, special-characters

I'm using jQuery to load a .htm file into a div on my main page, but when I do so, special character such as æ, ø, and å turns into a '�'.. any ideas on how to display the characters correctly ?

Comment: You probably won't get an answer unless you accept answers for your other questions: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1493595/mads-friis?tab=questions

Answer (score 0):

Use the character codes, the ones starting with &# (e.g. :&#162)